# Json Joining as in SQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, json

i have json objects like

```
{"COLORS":[[1,red],[2,yellow],[3,orange]]}

{"FRUITS":[[1,apple,1],[2,banana,2],[3,orange,3], [4,grenade,1], [5,apple,2]]}
```

i need to make them like:

```
{"FRUITS":[[1,apple,red],[2,banana,yellow],[3,orange,orange], [4,grenade,red], [5,apple,yellow]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a simple nested loop is the simplest way to solve this.
As far as i know there is no "json join" feature in javascript.

Try this:

```js
var colors = {"COLORS":[[1,"red"],[2,"yellow"],[3,"orange"]]};
var fruits = {"FRUITS":[[1,"apple",1],[2,"banana",2],[3,"orange",3], [4,"grenade",1], [5,"apple",2]]};
console.log(fruits);
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.FRUITS.length; i++) {
 var temp = fruits.FRUITS[i];
 for (var j = 0; j < colors.COLORS.length; j++) {
  if (colors.COLORS[j][0] === temp[2]) {
   temp[2] = colors.COLORS[j][1];
   break;
  }
 };
 fruits.FRUITS[i] = temp;
};
console.log(fruits);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to help you iterating over array. And also use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find a `color` related to id in `fruits` array.

```
var colors = {"COLORS":[[1,"red"],[2,"yellow"],[3,"orange"]]};
var fruits = {"FRUITS":[[1,"apple",1],[2,"banana",2],[3,"orange",3], [4,"grenade",1], [5,"apple",2]]}

var f = fruits.FRUITS;

$.each(f, function(i, fruitItem) {
    var colorItem = colors.COLORS.filter(function(color) {
        return color[0] == fruitItem[2]
    });

    fruitItem[2] = colorItem[0][1]
});

console.log(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another similar method to finnmich, using `filter()` instead of a nested loop.

This builds a new array and ignores entries which do not have matching ids, like a sql join:

```js
var c = {"COLORS":[[1,"red"],[2,"yellow"],[3,"orange"]]};

var f = {"FRUITS":[[1,"apple",1],[2,"banana",2],[3,"orange",3], [4,"grenade",1], [5,"apple",2]]};

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < f.FRUITS.length; i++)
{
    var entry = f.FRUITS[i];
    var id = entry[2];
    var color = c.COLORS.filter(function(v) {
        return v[0] == id;
    });

    if(color.length > 0) {
        result.push([entry[0], entry[1], color[0][1]]);
    }
}

console.dir(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). It assumes that $colors and $fruits contain the JSON values for 'colors' and 'fruits' respectively:

```
$colors.COLORS | map( {(.[0]|tostring): .[1] } ) | add as $dict
| $fruits
| .FRUITS |= map( (.[2]) |= $dict[tostring] )
```

The example below shows how to set $coloars and $fruits.

If your jq has INDEX/1, the first line above could be shortened to:

```
$colors.COLORS | INDEX(.[0]) | map_values(.[1]) as $dict
```

#### Explanation

The first line produces a dictionary ($dict), which is then used to make the translation.

#### Example

Assuming colors.json and fruits.json hold valid JSON values corresponding to the example give in the question, and that program.jq holds the above jq program, the invocation:

```
jq -n --argfile colors colors.json --argfile fruits fruits.json -f program.jq
```

yields:

```
{"FRUITS":[[1,"apple","red"],[2,"banana","yellow"],[3,"orange","orange"],[4,"grenade","red"],[5,"apple","yellow"]]}
```